# What is the best way to store and collect data for analytics?

Tags: javascript, architecture, analytics

To preface, I realize this is a very high-level question but I'm looking for input on how to best architect the solutions rather than how to implement it.

What I have so far is as follows:

1. Since we use multiple tracking vendors, each vendor's tracking code is wrapped in an object that standardizes the tracking methods. The idea is that no matter which tracking vendor is used certain methods are always available to be called, rendering the vendors essentially interchangeably.
2. Every vendor wrapper accepts a tracking rules object that provides instructions on what to track and when. *For example the tracking rules object includes an onDOMReady, onFormSubmit and onDOMChange method that is executed at the appropriate time.*

What I am currently struggling with is the best approach when it comes to collecting data on the events. In the past the rules object had always gathered data the following ways:

- Parsing the current URL *(based on the known URL structure)*.
- Scraping the DOM for the values in tags *(like the h1 or title)* and attributes *(like form name)*
- Digging through the various instantiated JS objects in search of other data. *For example pulling a user's id from user.current.id.*

This has been useful in the past as it allowed tracking to perform behind the scenes. Of course the collection methods above all required people to be careful what they change as seemingly safe to change object and DOM structures can have a dramatic affect on tracking. With a lot of different people contributing to the code we're looking for a better way to handle data collection.

Some ideas that have surfaced are:

- Use data binds to store all tracking information in the DOM. This has the advantage of being transparent, but the disadvantage of leading to verbosity. In addition, if used exclusively it'll require data that only exists in JS objects to be transferred to the DOM.
- Continue to use our non-intrusive methods, but write more extensive unit tests. *(This is a no-brainer, but I'd love to pair this with a cleaner data collection process, to make it a less daunting task)*

Are there any best practices, philosophies or suggestions that may help?